# The request hostname is invalid requesting ASP.Net Core 3.1 from Flutter on Android Emulator

Tags: android, asp.net, rest, http, flutter

I have a flutter app (Android Emulator) and localhost rest API. I'm trying to connect to the API from the app, but the hostname is invalid. I tried localhost, 10.0.2.2 and my IP address in the call, but it was not working. In addition I use http instead of https because I read that sometimes Android have problems with the self-signed certificates.

Here's the flutter code:

```
  Future<String> getData() async {
    var response = await http.get(
      Uri.encodeFull('http://10.0.2.2:54010/api/groups/745238'),
      headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json"
      }
    );
    print(response.body);
  }
```

Response body:

```
I/flutter ( 4892): <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
I/flutter ( 4892): <HTML><HEAD><TITLE>Bad Request</TITLE>
I/flutter ( 4892): <META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" Content="text/html; charset=us-ascii"></HEAD>
I/flutter ( 4892): <BODY><h2>Bad Request - Invalid Hostname</h2>
I/flutter ( 4892): <hr><p>HTTP Error 400. The request hostname is invalid.</p>
I/flutter ( 4892): </BODY></HTML>
```

The asp.net core 3.1 endpoint:

```
[HttpGet("{pin}")]
public ActionResult<Group> GetByPin(string pin)
{
    try
    {
        var group = Service.GetByPin(pin);
        return Ok(group);
    }
    catch
    {
        return BadRequest();
    }
}
```

I can confirm that I get the data in the browser as well as on postman. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue; connecting to webAPI from Android emulator. Solution worked for me is to change C:\Repo.vs\MyProject\config\applicationhost.config. Check if you have similar lines for the binding tag. You should have the line:

```html
<binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:54140:127.0.0.1" />
```

(the port number '54140 should be changed to match yours.)

```html
  <system.applicationHost>
   <sites>
      <site name="WebSite1" id="1" serverAutoStart="true">
        <application path="/">
          <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="%IIS_SITES_HOME%\WebSite1" />
        </application>
        <bindings>
          <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation=":8080:localhost" />
        </bindings>
      </site>
      <site name="PetCareLogWebApi" id="2">
        <application path="/" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
          <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\Repos\MyProject" />
        </application>
        <bindings>
          

<binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:54140:127.0.0.1" />

          <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:54140:localhost" />
        </bindings>
      </site>
```

Comment: Thank you man, you and my colleague saved my day with this!